# How to check who is the owner for the triggers in my Google Apps Script file?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

As you can see, my colleagues's Google Apps Script has a disabled triggers, its does say that the reason is - The account for the owner of this trigger has been disabled. It is related to the owner of the triggers?I want to know who is the owner for the triggers (as it was shown in the picture, the owner is 'Other user') ?

[image: My Triggers page interface]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Google Apps Script hasn't a method to retrieve the trigger owner. If the trigger did changes to a file the owner might be found in the file history / Drive activity. If the trigger logs the effective user name it might be possible to find it in the logs.